# GET Ajax returns html code in response instead of json object

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, openshift

I have an ajax get request as below. I am making a GET request to server.js in openshift using nodejs express. However, i get html contents in the response method instead of json object. Both the requests are for the same domain.The node modules that I am using are moongojs,mongodb and bson.

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "http://abc-favspot.rhcloud.com",
           contentType: "application/json",
           data: JSON.stringify(currLocation),
           dataType: "text",
           success: function(response){
           callback(response);
               },
            error: function( error ){
            console.log( "ERROR:", error );

                }
            });
```

My server.js file has the following code

```
self.routes['getData'] = function(req, res){
        console.log("gat method");            

    self.db.collection('location').find().toArray(function(err, names) {
       res.header("Content-Type:","application/json");
        console.log("success get");            
        res.send(names);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Try simplifying the request first. Don't make a db call, simple return some JSON in your `server.js`.

Do this to make sure that you are calling the correct route.

Comment: btw, if `callback` takes response as a parameter, you don't have to wrap it in a function, i.e. : `success: callback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.send(names)` is not JSON, You have to stringify the data using `JSON.stringify`.

Try testing before the DB call to check if it works.

`res.send( JSON.stringify( {testData:'test'} ) )`

**Edit**

As discussed in the comments, please check to ensure that your request is routed to the correct route that you declared.

Does `console.log("gat method");` output anything to the terminal window?

Comment: I have removed the dataType from ajax call,but it still didnt work

Comment: Changed the answer to point to some issues with your server code.

Comment: I tried the stringify, but it didnt work. i still get the html as response

Comment: what html do you get? are you certain that your request is routed to the correct route?

Comment: I am getting the original html page, which the user uses it for get request

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your routing. You need to route to the correct action. From what I see above, `self.routes['getData']` should point to `http://abc-favspot.rhcloud.com/getData`. What router are you using? Does `console.log("gat method");` output anything to the terminal window?

Comment: thats the thing, it doesnt even go in the self.routes['getData'].Hence no output.

Comment: self.app.get('/', self.routes['getData']); calls self.routes['getData']

Comment: Could you edit your post to include your node modules you are using?

Comment: I have updated my post to add  node modules. It's in the first paragrapg, last line

Comment: When i do   self.app.get('/ws', self.routes['/']); where the ajax request is the same as you suggested, i get the output from self.app.get. But it gets displayed on the webapge, i want this response back in ajax request, so that I can populate in my html page

Comment: Thank you, for pointing out the routing. I fixed it.                 In url section of the ajax get request I updated it to           url: "http://abc-favspot.rhcloud.com/index". and in server.js file I used   self.app.get('/index', self.routes['getData']);

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of help. I'll edit the answer so you can close this question!

Answer (score 1):

in your `$.ajax` method call change this

```
dataType: "text",
```

to

```
dataType: "json",
```

refer to the documentation for the further details

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and please check if the data you receive is a valid json, check it with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I did as you said. I also removed the dataType from ajax call, still it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `res.json` to send JSON response instead of `res.send`

```
res.json(obj)
```

This method also set `Content-Type` as `application/json`