# AJAX returns HTML code with output

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

After trying some solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208449/get-ajax-returns-html-code-in-response-instead-of-json-object) and many other questions I wasn't able to get what is exact problem in my code. My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#botname").blur(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/tukaiexotic/rq/requisition/typhead",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result) {
                $("#commmonname").val(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It returns my expected result, but with result, it returns the HTML code of the whole page.

What is wrong in code?

Server side script

```
function typhead_mod()
        {

             $this->db->select("fa_id,fa_code,fa_name");
            $aaa=$this->db->get('tukai_farms')->result();

            echo strip_tags($aaa);

        }
```

Comment: change your serverside script to change the returned value

Comment: Didn't work. Exactly what you want me to do?

Comment: check whether the script is error free or not?

Comment: Can u add your server side script here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use strip_tags while sending data from server file if that is in php like below-

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test2.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result) {
                //alert(result);
                $("#commmonname").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="commmonname"></div>
```

SERVER file

```
<?php
$msg="<h2>HI</h2>";
echo strip_tags($msg);
?>
```

Comment: I have added server script please take a look.

Comment: u took the wrong variable ..see $saa and $aaa. Also plz give the data which is coming from the database so we can see its format..

Comment: How to validate that a query to the database returns results validate with if in the AJAX response?

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot and finally i got the solution using below code.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "page name/method name",
     data: '{ param 1: "value", param 2: "value" }',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (data) {}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    URL: "<?= base_url()?>/controller name/function name",  
    type: 'POST',
    data: {school_code:school_code,class_name:class_name},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(res)
    {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Actually the real problem in this case is URL. if the URL is not set properly then function will not call and Ajax will return the same page content in response. so please check your URL and set it like above.