# Ajax Return HTML Code with my expected output

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After trying some solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826231/ajax-returns-html-code-with-output) and many other questions I wasn't able to get what is exact problem in my code. My code

```
$('#genoffer').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var offerstatus  = $('#offerstatus').val();

     if ($.trim(offerstatus) != '') {
              $.ajax({
                url:'general_create.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{offerstatus:offerstatus},
                dataType: 'text',
                success:function(data){
                    if ($.trim(data) == 'gsent') {
                        alert(data);
                    }else if($.trim(data) == 'agsent'){
                        alert(data);
                    }else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
              });
     }else{
        alert('empty');
     }

  });
```

my script are given below

```
 public function generalOfferLetter($offerstatus){
          if ($offerstatus == 1) {
              echo "gsent";
              exit();
          }elseif($offerstatus == 2){
             echo "agsent";
             exit();
          }else{
            echo "agsent";
          }


        }
```

It returns my expected result, but with result, it returns the HTML code of the whole page.

What is wrong in code?

general_create.php

```
 $offerstatus = $_POST["offerstatus"];
  $bookingsearch->generalOfferLetter($offerstatus);
```

Comment: please share the content of `general_create.php` page

Comment: There is nothing wrong, this is the expected behavior of AJAX. If you want to change what is returned you need to write something that will return only what you want.

Comment: @JayBlanchard if there is no wrong. then why ajax return HTML code with my expected result?

Comment: I want my expected result no html code. then what will i do expert?

Comment: You write something that will return exactly what you want.

Comment: Try with Try with `ob_flush();` inside `generalOfferLetter`. Also, you are missing `exit()` statement at the end of function.

Comment: @mokiSRB I tried by giving ob_flush(); inside my method.but same result.

Answer (score -1):

Please use Below code :

Add  **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"**

```
$('#genoffer').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var offerstatus  = $('#offerstatus').val();

     if ($.trim(offerstatus) != '') {
              $.ajax({
                url:'general_create.php',
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "html",
                method: 'POST',
                data:{offerstatus:offerstatus},

                success:function(data){
                    if ($.trim(data) == 'gsent') {
                        alert(data);
                    }else if($.trim(data) == 'agsent'){
                        alert(data);
                    }else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
              });
     }else{
        alert('empty');
     }

  });
```

Comment: I used it.my output doesn't appear. it returns only the HTML code

Comment: Nope, he returns the whole html code. It won't help. He need to change Controller method.

Comment: I set datatype="html" instead of "text" try to use that may be it will help you

Comment: @KrishnaSavani I have changed dataType text to HTML it doesn't help me.

Comment: I have set again   dataType: 'text' but in php file 'general_create.php' add this line at starting  

`ob_end_clean();`

`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

and at the end in function add die()

Comment: Ok Finally I solved my problem. I included header file inside my general_create.php file which is contained html code that's why ajax returned my html code with expected result.