# AJAX request returns unwanted HTML code along with requested data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've the SET the following AJAX request. The url is actually a file called "Controller.php", and from this it can be understood that, it is a MVCish styled project.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1/Controller/fetch",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    function: 'fetch'
                },
                success: function(data){ var string = JSON.stringify(data); var json = JSON.parse(string);
                    $("#div#id").html(json);
                }
            });
```

This is the code in the "Controller.php":

```
<?php
class Controller extends Base_controller{
public function fetch(){
if(isset($_POST['function'])){
// Execute a SQL Query and return data
echo json_encode($result_of_the_query);
}
}
}
```

The request works perfectly and fetches the requested data, but also brings some unwanted HTML code from a page (index.php - everything is routed from here), as shown below: I tried `echo strip_tags(json_encode($result_of_the_query));`, as mentioned here [AJAX returns HTML code with output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826231/ajax-returns-html-code-with-output). But it didn't work. What modification should I do in my code??

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> --> <script src="/vector/js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script> [{"column_one":"14-Jun-2020","column_two":null,"column_three":null},{"column_one":"07-Jun-2020","column_two":null,"column_three":null}]
```

My bootstrap.php file is very similar to:

```
// Load Config (database)
  require_once 'config/config.php';

  // Load Helpers
  require_once 'helpers/url_helper.php';
  require_once 'helpers/session_helper.php';

  // Autoload Core Libraries
  spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    require_once 'libraries/' . $className . '.php';
  });
```

Comment: remove all `html` code from your calling page .

Comment: @Swati all it consists of are, CDNs to Bootstrap, JQuery, etc..Removing those will result in paralysing my project permanantly

Comment: @NoOorZ24, turns out with return all of the intended data is gone and all that remains is the HTML code hahaha..

Comment: @NoOorZ24 exactly. return the response or stop the process once the response is sent. die or exit() maybe.

Comment: @VivekChoudhary the echo is the last command to run in that script, do you really think `die()` will be helpful here? And if you still insist, I tried it and guess what... It doesn't work.

Comment: @kerbh0lz Yes, Exactly. But what has that got to do with this??

Comment: @VivekChoudhary Yes.

Comment: @kerbh0lz But how can I tell the bootstrap file to not include the HTML stuff?? In fact I haven't coded for anything that would bring the HTML code along with it??

Comment: @kerbh0lz I've added my bootstrap file can you suggest some changes please??

Comment: -- The url is actually a file called "Controller.php"        this is not true in that file only a class is instantiated. `fetch()` function is never called.

Comment: @dehart why do you think I get an output then??

Comment: You are sending it to the output somewhere in your code. you could call `debug_print_backtrace()` in your `fetch()` function to output a list of files/lines the code goes through